# How does the "managedObjectContext" method work?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm just beginning to learn how to use Core Data. The tutorial that I'm [learning from](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/) feels very helpful so far. In the part where they hook up the view controller where we want to store data to core data, they didn't explain the process of the method that does this "magic".

It's an implementation of the method `managedObjectContext`, so I thought it could be helpful if I post it here and you can explain to me/us what is the process that is being done here:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }

    return context;
}
```

Also for some reason when I'm returning the context object it's not in regular colour when I'm returning a class object, its just white:

[image]

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Here, we acquire a reference to the application delegate. This is an instance of the class that XCode generated for you (which should have the name `[Prefix of your project]AppDelegate`).

`[UIApplication sharedApplication]` returns a singleton object. Singleton is a design pattern which can basically be summed up as "if you call this method, it will *always* return the same object." So what that means here is that we are always getting the same application delegate whenever we call this in the program.

```
 if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
```

I'm actually kind of at a loss for why the tutorial wants you to call `performSelector:` here, `respondsToSelector:` seems a lot more appropriate, and `performSelector:` will raise an exception if your `delegate` object isn't of the right class anyway, so there's no point in guarding the actual message with an if statement.

If you ignore what seems to me to be unnecessary boilerplate, all you're doing is calling a method on the app delegate singleton. You can look it up in your project and see what it does -- judging by the context, it returns an `NSManagedObjectContext` class.

```
return context;
```

Note that this is *not* actually returning a class object, but instead a instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`. Therefore, the color white is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

What that code is doing is

1. Looking up the app delegate object. This is probably called something like `AppDelegate` in your project. This code finds the singleton by asking the shared `UIApplication` instance for its delegate.
2. Checking that the app delegate has a method named `managedObjectContext`.
3. If so, calling that method, and returning the result.

This is a lousy way to do it. Much better would be to declare a property on the view controller:

```
@property (readwrite, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Then assign a value to it when creating the view controller

```
newViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

That is, pass the managed object context around, assigning it to whatever object needs to use it. Don't assume that you can always look it up from the app delegate, because that will break if you ever change that part of your app delegate.

Xcode uses that color because it's a local variable in that method. Whether it's an object or some other type doesn't matter.